# How to upgrade Heroku Leiningen version?

Tags: clojure, heroku, leiningen

When deploying a clojure app to Heroku, I see it is using "cached Leiningen 1.6.2

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 271, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (205/205), done.
Writing objects: 100% (251/251), 737.28 KiB | 583 KiB/s, done.
Total 251 (delta 48), reused 234 (delta 41)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Clojure app detected
-----> Using cached Leiningen 1.6.2
       Downloading: rlwrap-0.3.7
       Writing: lein script
-----> Installing dependencies and compiling with Leiningen
...
```

I would like to upgrade to 1.7.0 so I can take advantage of the `:plugins` feature in the `project.clj`.

How can I have Heroku upgrade the version of Leiningen on my cedar stack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... I'm working on it. =) I haven't announced 1.7.0 yet because I've gotten a bug report I haven't been able to reproduce, but once I get a chance to investigate and fix if applicable I'll have it in the official buildpack. In the mean time you can use a custom BUILDPACK_URL to point to the lein-1.7 branch:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure.git#lein-1.7
```

Comment: Thanks, Phil. I'll look forward to the "release" 1.7 to Heroku. I have a workaround for the time being but I appreciate you answering my question.

Comment: This is useful to know even 4 years later, as the current version of Leiningen in the Heroku Clojure buildpack is broken, and a workaround is to use this trick to point to a previous working version.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change the version using a customized [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure).
You can then specify the version in bin/compile :

```
# install leiningen jar
LEIN_VERSION="1.6.2"
LEIN_JAR_URL="https://heroku-buildpack-clojure.s3.amazonaws.com/leiningen-$LEIN_VERSION-standalone.jar"
LEIN_JAR_PATH="$CACHE_DIR/leiningen-$LEIN_VERSION-standalone.jar"
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work though. I'd suggest you wait for Heroku to update Leiningen :)